# Comma-separated repeats

Tags: regex

I've got a pretty long regex to match an entry in a list I'm processing. The list should be one or more of these entries, comma-separated. Consider a regex:

```
([abc]+|[123]+)
```

for the entry. To match my comma-separated list, I'm matching against something like this:

```
([abc]+|[123]+)(,([abc]+|[123]+))*
```

(It looks especially foolish with my nasty regex instead of the short one I used here for the example)

I feel there must be a better way than having two copies of the entry -- once for the first entry, again for and follow comma/entry pairs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this perhaps:

```
((?!=^|,)([abc123]))+
```

Broke down it's:

```
(                       # start of parent capture
  (?!=^|,)                # look ahead and find either the start of a line or a comma
  ([abc123])              # actual pattern to look for (token)
)+                      # say this whole pattern is repeatable
```

**[PHP Demo](http://www.ideone.com/6I772)** (Was simplest way to demonstrate)

Comment: I don't think you want the `!` in your look ahead (which is for a negative look ahead), but a look ahead doesn't actually match a character, so this won't match. You should be fine without lookahead `(?:(?:^|,)([a-c1-3]))+`

Comment: @jswolf19: I use that to avoid the character winding up in the match. I guess personal preference. -- the combination also gives me both the first match and the rest. (without it I will either get only the first token, or the 2nd-onward)

Comment: I know you don't want the ',' in the match, but it has to be matched: if you have 'a,1', then your regex won't match it. the lookahead sees the ',', but it's still there when you try to match the 1 because the lookahead doesn't throw the ',' away. You need a non-capturing group for that `(?: )`.

Comment: @jswolf: Not sure [what you mean](http://regexr.com?2t8nc)? Your method only gives me the last match. (In your example, start of line would match first, then the comma counts towards the next match)

Comment: take off the global flag, and your's [doesn't match](http://regexr.com?2t8nf) the entire string is what I mean. Nifty site, though.

Comment: @jswolf19 is correct, `(?!=^|,)` is a negative lookahead for `=` followed by the beginning of the string (which is impossible), or a comma.  Being a *negative* lookahead, it will always succeed without ever trying the `,` alternative.

Comment: @Alan: `(?!=)` is a negative look ahead, where the equals sign is parthe syntax. Where as `(?!<)` would be a look behind.

Comment: Sorry, but no.  Negative lookahead is formed from the positive version, not by *adding* a `!`, but by *replacing* the `=` with it.  Lookbehind (a much "younger" feature) adds `<` to the lookahead syntax, but *negative* lookbehind is then formed the same way as negative lookahead: by replacing the `=` with `!`.

Answer (score 10):

<strike>Looks like you want **[backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)**.</strike>

```
([abc123])(,\1)*
```

Also, just FYI, `[abc]|[123]` is equivalent to `[abc123]`.

---

**Edit:** Based on your edit, I think I misunderstood what you were trying to do. Try this:

```
([abc123]+(,|$))*
```

Or if you want to be less restrictive:

```
([^,]+(,|$))*
```

This matches strings of non-comma characters separated by commas. A simpler approach would just be a global match for `[^,]+` by itself. In JavaScript, that would look like this:

```
myString.match(/[^,]+/g) //or /[abc123]+/g, or whatever
```

Or you could just split on commas:

```
myString.split(/,/)
```

Comment: that's going to say that the next token has to be the same as the previous, not that it must fit the pattern. (not sure that's what the OP wants, they're just curious if they need to specify the pattern twice [I could be wrong...])

Comment: @Brad: Isn't that what he's going for? Maybe I'm confused.

Comment: @JustinEMorgan: Maybe you're right. I read it as "do I need to specify the pattern to look for twice?", and "if not, how do I avoid doing so".

Comment: I edited my question. I'm really just looking for a way to extend a pattern to a comma-separated list of itself.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I'm testing the entire line.

```
/(?!^,)^((^|,)([abc]+|[123]+))+$/.test('a,b,c,1,2,3');
true
```

The negative lookahead excludes an initial comma.

```
/(?!^,)^((^|,)([abc]+|[123]+))+$/.test(',a,b,c,1,2,3');
false
```

If you need the individual components do a simple split after validation.

I'm validating PLSS subdivisional sections and subsections.

```
// Check for one or more Section Specs consisting of an optional
// subsection followed by an "S" and one or two digits. Multiple
// Section Specs are separated by space or a comma and optional space.
//
// Example: SW/4 SW/4 S1, E/2 S2, N/2 N/2 S12
//
// Valid subsections are -
//  (1) [NS][EW]/4\s+[NS][EW]/4   eg. NW/4 SE/4 (40 ac)
//  (2) [NSEW]/2\s+[NS][EW]/4     eg. N/2 SE/4 (80 ac)
//  (3) [NS]/2\s+[NS]/2           eg. N/2 S/2 (160 ac)
//  (4) [EW]/2\s+[EW]/2           eg. E/2 W/2 (160 ac)
//  (5) [NS][EW]/4                eg. NE/4 (160 ac)
//  (6) [NSEW]/2                  eg. E/2 (320 ac)
//  (7) 1/1                       Shorthand for the full section (640 ac)
//
// Expressions like E/2 N/2 are not valid. Use NE/4 instead.
// Expressions like NW/4 E/2 are not valid. You probably want W/2 NE/4.

var pat = '' +
    '(([NS][EW]/4|[NSEW]/2)\\s+)?[NS][EW]/4\\s+' +    // (1), (2) & (5)
    '|([NS]/2\\s+)?[NS]/2\\s+' +                      // (3) & part of (6)
    '|([EW]/2\\s+)?[EW]/2\\s+' +                      // (4) & part of (6)
    '|1/1\\s+';                                       // (7)

pat = '(' + pat + ')?' + 'S\\d{1,2}';                 // a Section Spec

// Line anchors, join alternatives and negative lookahead to exclude an initial comma
pat = '(?!^,)^((^|,\\s*|\\s+)(' + pat + '))+$';

var re = new RegExp(pat, 'i');

console.log(pat);
(?!^,)^((^|,\s*|\s+)(((([NS][EW]/4|[NSEW]/2)\s+)?[NS][EW]/4\s+|([NS]/2\s+)?[NS]/2\s+|([EW]/2\s+)?[EW]/2\s+|1/1\s+)?S\d{1,2}))+$
```

Once validated I split using a positive lookbehind.

```
var secs = val.split(/(?<=S\d+)(,\s*|\s+)/i);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am ignoring group-capturing challenges and treating this as only a validation problem i.e. *whether the given string is a valid CSV for my use-case or not*.

The simplest answer is

```
/((^|,)([abc]+|[123]+))+/
```

This however allows a few cases that may not be desirable

```
,ab,31,ca         # leading comma
ab,31,ca,         # trailing comma
xy,ab,31,ca,76    # leading or trailing invalid values
```

To address these cases, you can use

```
^((^(?!,)|(?!^),)([abc]+|[123]+))+$
```

```
^                     # don't allow leading invalid values
((
  ^(?!,)              # beginning, not starting with a comma
|                     # OR
  (?!^),              # not beginning, need a comma             
)(                    # followed by
  [abc]+|[123]+       # pattern for your valid values
))+                   # one or more times
$                     # don't allow trailing invalid values
```

This ensures no leading or trailing commas, and matches the whole line.